# Get all values of Listbox as a list

Tags: winforms, listbox, vb.net-2010

This should be simple, but it certainly hasn't been simple for me. I have two listboxes, one is bound to a datatable the other is not bound to anything. Users can select records from the bound listbox and add them to the unbound listbox. I want to retrieve the contents of the unbound box as a list and provide the list as input to another class, I'm struggling to get the values from the unbound listbox. This is what my code looks like:

```
    Dim selectedT = (From i In lbSelectedT.Items).ToList()

    For Each T In selectedT
        MsgBox(T.ToString)

    Next

    ' output is: System.Data.DataRowView
```

What am I not doing right?

Comment: How are you moving the items to the second list box?  What are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 0):

Your second list box should be bound the same as the first.  Then while looping over the items treat them exactly like the source data.

The following binds to a list of listOption objects.  When you click button2 it loops over the items, implicitly casts them to listOption then accesses the data.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        options.Add(New listOption("test 1", 1))
        options.Add(New listOption("test 2", 2))
        options.Add(New listOption("test 3", 3))
        options.Add(New listOption("test 4", 4))

        ListBox1.DataSource = options


        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "name"
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "id"

        ListBox2.DisplayMember = "name"
        ListBox2.ValueMember = "id"

    End Sub

    Public Property options As New List(Of listOption)
    Public Class listOption
        Public Property name As String
        Public Property id As Integer

        Sub New(name As String, id As String)
            Me.name = name
            Me.id = id
        End Sub
    End Class

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If ListBox1.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim selectedT = (From i In ListBox2.Items).ToList()

        For Each T As listOption In selectedT
            MsgBox(T.name.ToString)

        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```